# Why is it that we can consider the trajectory of an object in both directions and still get the correct answer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, time-reversal-symmetry

Sorry for the unclear title. Here is the question:

[image: an image of the problem]

why is it that we can "reverse the motion" as if the ball was being shot from the left and up towards the roof at the angle $\theta$? Is it because the kinetic energy needed to move the ball from the ground to the roof is the same as the gravitational potential energy of the ball on the roof?

Comment: the time reversibility of Newton's Laws has been a hot topic of discussion for centuries by now!

Comment: Because in this textbook problem, friction is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that we can "reverse the motion" ?

This is because the equations of motion in a simple ballistics problem like this are time symmetric i.e. they do not change if we reverse the direction of time (or, equivalently, replace the time co-ordinate $t$ with $-t$). This is connected at a deep level with the conservation of energy.

In scenarios where energy is dissipated into the environment (e.g. if friction or drag is involved, or there is an inelastic collision) then the equations of motion are *not* time symmetric, and you cannot just "reverse the motion".

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse it like the comment said, but it has not only the potential energy, but also the kinetic energy of the horizontal velocity wich is easy to find with 25m in 1,5s